# Oracle Apex 5 Opening page in new window

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am using Oracle Apex 5. On the page i have two items that are filled out (dynamic actions automatically refresh an interactive report based on the values of those two items).

Also i have a button PRINT which is supposed to open a new page and send the values of the two items. Since i want this new page to open in a new window(tab) i am doing it by making the action of the button redirect to url and entering this Javascript in the url:

```
javascript:var myWindow = window.open('f p=800:105:&APP_SESSION.::NO::REP_NAME,PAR1_NAME,PAR1_VAL,PAR2_NAME,PAR2_VAL:NarudzbenicaDobavljacV2,P_ACCOUNT_ID,&P15_SUPLIER_ID.,P_DATE,&P15_DATE.');
```

Here is the catch! The function doesn't pick up the values. Only after a page submit or refresh (F5) does it work. How to make it work without having to do this?

I also tried making the button a submit page action and adding an after submit branch with the same javascript, but this just throws a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you need to use the function [$v()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/GUID-B4DC6729-ED57-49F1-B18C-1EB1053E7421.htm#AEAPI417) to get the item value. The &PX_ITEM. notation doesn't work like that, this uses the session values stored in the database (which are set upon page submition or by a pl/sql block setting the [session state](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/GUID-62AA4333-160D-44FD-9F07-D188A2F4BC55.htm#AEAPI181)). You need to set the url like this:

```
javascript:var myWindow = window.open('f?p=800:105:&SESSION.::NO::REP_NAME,PAR1_NAME,PAR1_VAL,PAR2_NAME,PAR2_VAL:NarudzbenicaDobavljacV2,' + $v('P_ACCOUNT_ID') + ',' + $v('P15_SUPLIER_ID') +',' +$v('P_DATE') + ',' + $v('P15_DATE')');
```

Comment: Hello, i tried this way of building the link and it doesn't work. When i press the button nothing happens.

Comment: I have to note that the item P15_SUPLIER_ID is a popup LOV, and P15_DATE is a date picker. I don't know if that makes a difference for the notation.

Comment: I've noticed that you're missing the question mark in the url "f?p", and you should try &SESSION. instead of &APP_SESSION.

Comment: don't worry about that...i've noticed it too and fixed it..still doesn't work

Comment: Changing to &SESSION does nothing also.  I've made peace with putting a submit page action on the change event of the date picker (because the user has to pick a date anyways), so the original javascript works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If this question is still open try this:

```
javascript:var myWindow = window.open('f?p=800:105:&SESSION.::NO::REP_NAME,PAR1_NAME,PAR1_VAL,PAR2_NAME,PAR2_VAL:NarudzbenicaDobavljacV2,P_ACCOUNT_ID,' + $v("P15_SUPLIER_ID") +',P_DATE,' + $v("P15_DATE"));
```