# Oracle Apex 5 Open Page in new Tab/Window with Checksum

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

In Oracle Apex 5 I want to open a page for printing. Because there is no top- and side menu (to safe space and ink) I want to open the page in a new tab.

As mentioned on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39411560/oracle-apex-5-opening-page-in-new-window) I use `javascript` and `window.open`. But I have to use parameters and APEX requires a valid checksum.

So I filled a (hidden) field with

```
BEGIN
   return APEX_UTIL.PREPARE_URL(
      p_url => 'f?p=' || v('APP_ID') || ':310:'||v('APP_SESSION')||'::NO::P310_YEAR,P310_DEPT:'||v('P300_YEAR')||','||v('P300_DEPT'),
      p_checksum_type => 'SESSION');
END;
```

and use a button with "redirect to URL"

```
javascript:var x=window.open($v('P300_URL'));
```

But every time I clicked on this button, a new tab opens (fine!) but I have to sign in again to my application in the new tab AND the old tab.

Why is my session killed?

After signin in, the URL seems to be escaped (`%26amp%3Bcs%3D` instead of `&cs=`).

I'm googling for hours, but noone seems to have this problem, or I am the problem myself.

Comment: Try this reference http://recxltd.blogspot.com.au/2013/07/oracle-apex-url-checksums-and-jquery.html

Comment: That is exactly my approach

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. In my DA, set Value, I leaved "Escape Special Characters" enabled. After disabling, it works well. m(

The problem was not transparent, because escaping was not visible in the "Display only" field.

Comment: oh what a pain!